# Can I use subfolders in electron fiddle?

Tags: architecture, electron

Is this possible or not? I prefer to use fiddle because its easier. I couldn't find anything about it in the docs. I want to use electron fiddle because i haven't been able to work out how to use electron builder. if you can help me with electron builder that would be appreciated, but i would prefer to use fiddle. Thanks for the help!